# Editing .php-Files adds ^M linebreak

Tags: wordpress, encoding, utf-8, phpstorm, line-breaks

Recently when I edit my Wordpress files, after saving, I get this annoying ^M with every line break. I was told that this is a Windows issue, which is kind of confusing cause i am using a MAC. For editing I use PHPStorm with UTF-8 setup. Additional I don't know much or nothing about encoding. Anybody can help?

Comment: Sorry .. I'm a bit confused here. What do you mean by `^M`? Are you talking about line ending (`CRLF` vs `LF`)?

Comment: I dont really know the difference but yes its the line ending if you want so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For brand new files** (created in IDE) you can change default line ending in `Preferences | Code Style | General | Line Separator`.

**For existing files** -- it is automatically detected for each file **individually**. You can change line ending at any time by changing `File | Line Separators` (or via right click in status bar in appropriate place -- where current line ending is displayed).

Answer (score 0):

if you can use a Vi editor.. open your file using vi ...

vi example.java

then press esc and type :

then type beside the colon %s/ctrl+v ctrl+M/

press enter/return

then press esc and :

now type wq

It would save the edits and ^M would be gone ..,,